# How do you retain correct table width in openstack when pipeing to less?

Tags: openstack

If you set `CLIFF_FIT_WIDTH=1`, openstack cli will fit table output to the screen width.

However, this breaks if you try and pipe to less.

It seems like a possible workaround could be: `alias openstack='openstack --max-width "$(tput cols)"'` but this seems hacky. Is there a flag or env var for openstack cli I missed so that I can pipe the output to less without the width breaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that because you're piping the output to another command, the `openstack` CLI is no longer attached to your terminal and isn't able to query the screen width.

I usually just run `openstack ... | less -S`, which sort of does the opposite: it disables the wrapping of long lines so that the table displayed isn't mucked up.

Your solution of injecting the output of `tput cols` seems a reasonable alternative.